# Is it possible to allow an old app to lock/unlock the phone?

Tags: lock-screens, permissions

I'm still using an old app to automate some things:
[Automated Device (com.dhr.automateddevice)](https://droidinformer.org/tools/automated-device/) by Daniel Herrero.
The app isn't update from about 8 years, but it stills works and do what i need, it is ads free and simple to use.

Meanwhile android security changed, and some functions do not works anymore. One of them is the ability to lock or unlock the phone (so, you don't have to unlock it from the lock screen). I use it when the phone connect to my car radio or my helmet bluetooth when i'm on my motorcycle.

I know that my phone has "Smartlock" settings which can do the same thing, but i use other phones also and i share the same "automations" with them.

So: there's a way to allow an old app to lock/unlock the phone?

Comment: The common way to bypass this unlock scenario is having an app running above the lock screen, so the phone is still locked but the one app above the lock screen is fully usable.